# How to get product_id / entity_id in Magento using Product URL

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9

I want to fetch product_id / entity_id from products url in Magento.

If anyone has done this before please let me know ..

Currently I can fetch all information using product_id.

But I want to fetch info using its product url -

Below is my code -

```
<?php
    $model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product') //getting product model

    $_product = $model->load($productid); //getting product object for particular product id

    echo $_product->getShortDescription(); //product's short description
    echo $_product->getDescription(); // product's long description
    echo $_product->getName(); //product name

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get the product id in a product page like this:

```
$product = Mage::registry('current_product');
$id = $product->getId();
```

and if you want to load product by url then use follows code:

```
$url = 'electronics/cameras/olympus-stylus-750-7-1mp-digital-camera.html';
$oRewrite = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite')
                ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                ->loadByRequestPath($url);
$product_id = $oRewrite->getProductId();

echo $product_id;
```

Comment: I am not able to understand. can you please write it in simple manner .. that `$url = url here and some code and then echo product_id `

Comment: I have edited my answer please do check second part of answer

Comment: Thanks, your answer solve my problem . I was using complete web url instead of as per your url .